# Python - Count characters between two specific strings

Tags: python, count

I made a text file containing random sequences of bases (ATCG) and want to find the longest and shortest "reading frame" within those sequences.

I was able to identify the Start- and Stop-Codons (the two "specific strings" mentioned) with "searchfile" and a for-loop and also know the basics of counting (example of code at the end) but I can't find any possibility to set those two as "boundaries" between I can count.

Can anybody perhaps give me a hint or tell me how such a function/operation is called so I can at least find it in a documentary or how it could look like? I found many options how to count various different things but none for counting between "x" and "y".

Example of how I looked up the strings between which I want to count:

```
searchfile = open('dna.txt', 'r')
for line in searchfile:
    if "ATG" in line: print (line)
searchfile.close()
```

whole code:

```
import numpy as np

BASES = ('A', 'C', 'T', 'G')
P = (0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)

def random_dna_sequence(length):
    return ''.join(np.random.choice(BASES, p=P) for _ in range(length))

with open('dna.txt', 'w+') as txtout:
    for _ in range(10):
        dna = random_dna_sequence(50)
        txtout.write(dna)
        txtout.write("\n")


searchfile = open('dna.txt', 'r')
for line in searchfile:
    if "ATG" in line: print (line)
searchfile.close()

searchfile = open('dna.txt', 'r')
for line in searchfile:
    if "ATG" in line: print (line)
    elif "TAG" in line: print (line)
    elif "TAA" in line: print (line)
    elif "TGA" in line: print (line)
    else: print ("no stop-codon detected")
searchfile.close()
```

Sidenote: The print instruction is only a temporary placeholder for testing. In the end i would like to set the found strings as mentioned "boundaries" (i can't find a better name for it) at that point.

Some example lines from the dna.txt file:

```
GAAGACGCAATAGGTTCACGGCGCTCATAGGCTTGCCCTCATAGGGCTTG
TCTGAGGTAGAAGGAGCTACTGCCGTTGCAGGTGACGCCCACAGTCCTGA
GTTATTACTCCCTGACTGTCATCTGTTCGGATACCGTGCAGCGCATCGAG
AGGAGATAACGCGATCCTGAGACAGTTTACCTATATGTTCACTACGCATG
CCGAGCTGATCCGACTACTGAAGGTGAATTCTGAAGCTAATCTGCAGTTC
```

This is a small example (I use 10 and 50 for testing) but in the end the file shall contain 10000 sequences with 1000 characters each.

Comment: can you give part of your input and expected output

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "input and expected output"? i'll edit the whole code into the initial post, maybe it will clarify at least something.

Comment: post some of the lines from dna.txt

Comment: I edited an example into the initial post.

Comment: GAAGACGCAATAGGTTCACGGCGCTCATAGGCTTGCCCTCATAGGGCTTG
this is your line what do expect from this line?
what do you want to count in these line

Comment: i want to count the characters between two specific strings (usually start- and stop-codons). f.e.: i want to look for "AGA" and "CCC" in each sequence and count the number of characters between them.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is something like this:

```
with open("dna.txt", 'r') as searchfile:
    all_dna = searchfile.read()
    start = all_dna.index("ATG")
    rem_dna = all_dna[start + 3:]
    end = rem_dna.index("ATG")
    needed_dna = all_dna[start:(end + 3)]
print len(needed_dna)
```

`index` finds where in a string the substring passed as an argument occurs, and will `raise ValueError` if the substring is not found. `with` is a keyword useful as a safety precaution for file I/O that ensures that the file is properly closed even if the code inside that block causes an error. If you don't want to include the starting and ending "ATG" in `needed_dna`, you can set that to `all_dna[(start + 3):end]`. The brackets, by the way, mean "take the substring of the specified string beginning at the argument before the colon (inclusive, zero-indexed) and ending at the argument after the colon (non-inclusive, also zero-indexed). This can also be used for lists, and can be used without the colon to get the character at a specific index. Hope this helps!